# Regarding header footer in another module in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am a new of Angular. I created header, footer and sidebar. And I was create dashboard component if I use in this dishoard component its works good. So it is working in component. then I created a module for employee. if i use Header Footer Sidebar in this employee module means its shows error

1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1

```
src/app/employee/list-employee/list-employee.component.ts:5:16
  5   templateUrl: './list-employee.component.html',
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Error occurs in the template of component ListEmployeeComponent.


Error: src/app/employee/list-employee/list-employee.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'app-sidebar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2 <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
```

src/app/employee/list-employee/list-employee.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './list-employee.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ListEmployeeComponent.

Error: src/app/employee/list-employee/list-employee.component.html:514:9 - error NG8001: 'app-footer' is not a known element:

1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

514         
~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/employee/list-employee/list-employee.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './list-employee.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component ListEmployeeComponent.

Please help me to sort out this error.

Comment: You should put the header, footer and sidebar components in a separate module that you can import in all the modules that have components which need to display them.

Comment: S i created header, footer, sidebar component seperately.

Comment: In another module? Then all you need to do is import the module that declares (and also exports) these components in the `EmployeeModule` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you put these components in a separate module, you can import it in all the other parts of your app that use the sidebar, header and footer.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SidebarComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    SidebarComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ]
})
export class LayoutModule { }
```

And in the employee module you can do something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // ...
  ],
  imports: [
    // ...
    LayoutModule,
  ],
})
export class EmployeeModule {}
```

Comment: thank u. will check and reply

Comment: Hi bro, its working, now shows another error like                                                             
Error: src/app/footer/footer.component.ts:8:14 - error NG6004: Present in the NgModule.exports of EmployeeModule but neither declared nor imported

Comment: Looks like you missed the step where you also need to specify the component name inside of the `declarations` array, not only inside `exports`. The error is pretty descriptive this time.